# python *list syntax error on server only, code working fine on local client

Tags: python, flask, python-3.6

When I execute my code on my external flask server, I get the following server-side error:

```
2017-12-03 02:40:53 ", line 
2017-12-03 02:40:53 430
2017-12-03 02:40:53 
2017-12-03 02:40:53     
2017-12-03 02:40:53 combinedheader = ["Protein", "MW", *listheadersSpC, *listheadersNSAF, *listheadersloge]
2017-12-03 02:40:53     
2017-12-03 02:40:53  
2017-12-03 02:40:53 ^
2017-12-03 02:40:53 SyntaxError
2017-12-03 02:40:53 : 
2017-12-03 02:40:53 invalid syntax
2017-12-03 02:40:53
```

This is the line of code that's causing grief:
`combinedheader = ["Protein", "MW", *listheadersSpC, *listheadersNSAF, *listheadersloge]`

Locally, the code runs just fine. Also note that the following code returns no errors when executed separately on the server:

```
list1 = ['a']
list2 = ['d' , 'e' , 'f']
list3 = ["Hi", "there", *list1, *list2]
print(list3)
```

Retuns: ['Hi', 'there', 'a', 'd', 'e', 'f']

EDIT: Code is running on a web app that's using a virtual environment for Python. Both the webapp and virtualenv python = 3.6. Local client running same version of python, same installed modules.

Comment: I think you have used the wrong version of python on server (probably 2.x). You'd better confirm the version number of server's python.

Comment: Thanks; I checked it before posting the question. Server: Version 3.6. Local: Version 3.6

Comment: Ah but you may be on to something. Perhaps the virtual environment I set up on the server isn't passing my code properly. Just checked again, and the main server uses 2.7.6, while my virtual env uses 3.6. That may be it; will report back.

Comment: Ok, my webapp is running 3.6, same as the associated virtual environment, even though the server bash is 2.x

Comment: Python 3 will not throw such exception. You can add `import sys; print(sys.version)` before that line to see which interpreter is exactly executing the code.

Comment: import sys; print(sys.version) gives me a printout of 3.6.0 :| Weird, hey.

Comment: Ok, here's something I noticed. Within my flask app.py, which reports 3.6.0, I call another python script using 'os.system("python myscript.py "'. I wonder what version of python that is.

Comment: If virtualenv hasn't been activated before you run your webapp, it will be python2.7.

Comment: Ah, guess what: Python 2.7.6. So how do I call 'os.system( run my python.app )' using the virtual environment's flavour of python. Perhaps: 'os.system("PATH TO PYTHON\python mypython.app ") '

Comment: May try: `import sys; os.system(sys.executable + ' myscript.py')`

Comment: Tried it. But I get an error: /usr/local/bin/uwsgipython: not found

So what I did was call the python3.6 within the virtual environment using: '"/PATH-TO-VENV/my-virtualenv/bin/python3.6 myapp.py"' And it worked!! (Format this as an answer, and I'll mark it correct for you). Thank you so much for your help, you're a legend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code `os.system("python myscript.py")` will not always use your current interpreter. Instead, it depends on the environment variables. So you must specify the absolute path of the interpreter explicitly.

For most of the cases, you can use `sys.executable` to get your current interpreter. However it doesn't work for uwsgi :-(, where `sys.executable` will return the path to uwsgi binary file. So in this case, you have to hard-code the executable path to the virtualenv interpreter like this: `os.system("path/to/venv/python myscript.py")`.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks for guiding me through the process